# Calc() function does not work in Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a Revolution slider in the homepage of my Wordpress site. I want to change its height with media queries using the CSS `Calc()` function as `height: calc(100% - 600px);`. It works everywhere else except my wordpress website. What could be the problem here?

Tried every browser, `webkit` `moz` and everything else. If i pass the height directly it works. But not with the `Calc()` function.

Comment: It has nothing to do with Wordpress. It is a CSS property.

Comment: I can think of 2 options: 1) specificity 2) the parent doesn't have a height specified and therefore the calculated percentage is not applied. If you can paste some code here or have a URL, we can help better.

Comment: Are you using any css pre-processors ? like less or sass?

Comment: @hunzaboy i know. Did u read the question?

Comment: @William No it's my personal host

Comment: @Gerard I think your second conclusion is exactly what i'm dealing with. Unfortunately i'm not in authority to expose the URL. :( Is there any general solution?

Comment: @HemaNandagopal Not to my knowledge.

Comment: @m4heshd you can add height:100%; to the parent. But if the grandparent doesn't have a height specified, you have the same problem. So check the whole tree.

Comment: @Gerard You are correct. It doesn't do any change. That means i have to go for another option right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end going with CSS wasn't an option for me. So i ended up resolving my issue using JS. Here's the solution for anybody who's having a similar issue.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
  if($(window).width() > 1600){
    $('.slider').height($(window).height() - 316);
  } 
  if($(window).width() < 767){
    $('.slider').height($(window).height() - 296);
  } 
});
```

Comment: You don't need to use JS at all. Use `100vh` to get the viewport height, and for the conditional styles, use media query.

Comment: @Terry nope. That doesn't do what i want.